# Windows authentication / SSO on using XCode on a Mac OS X machine to Subversion on Windows Server 2008

Tags: xcode, svn, windows-server-2008

I have been tasked to come up with a code repository to host our Objective-C code for in-house developed iOS apps. While we do have an existing Microsoft TFS instance, the available solutions to bridge TFS with XCode such as SVNBridge and Team Explorer Everywhere are a bit cumbersome and "hackish" for our requirements.

I'm recommending to use Subversion, but we are mainly a Microsoft house and use Windows authentication/SSO/Kerberos for our authentication requirements. My questions are as follows:

- Does SVN support these authentication protocols?
- Obviously we need to use Mac OS X/XCode for development - while Mac OS X can support windows domain authentication, how will this work if we need to integrate the authentication with SVN, using SSO?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some further research, I was able to find my own answers and also went further as to create a working proof-of-concept.

***Does SVN support these authentication protocols?***
From what I learned SVN can support Windows authentication by running SVN within Apache and using the SSPI modules to interact with your windows domain controller. These links were very helpful:

[Version Control Using SVN + Apache](http://csliu.com/2009/07/version-control-using-svn-apache/)

http://geekswithblogs.net/flanakin/archive/2005/08/31/51743.aspx

***Obviously we need to use Mac OS X/XCode for development - while Mac OS X can support windows domain authentication, how will this work if we need to integrate the authentication with SVN, using SSO?***
What's not clear to me here is what Xcode uses to authenticate to SVN - the Mac credentials OR the credentials entered when using svn in the command line. One thing i noticed is that Xcode will not work / connect or authenticate with SVN unless you do a checkout in the command line. I'm assuming Xcode uses these credentials in a way. Once a checkout has been performed and Xcode restarted, I am able to connect to my repositories without a hitch. There is also no need to enter the credentials in the username and password fields of your repository in Organizer.

It is important to note that what happens in the client side (Xcode and svn command-line) in terms of authentication is it's still Basic Auth, so your credentials are sent through the wire in clear base64 encoded text. SSL/TLS should be implemented to circumvent this risk.

Comment: Both links are failed